# How to create dynamically sized row heights based on downloaded image sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I’m trying to create dynamically sized row heights in my UITableView based on the aspect ratio of downloaded images from firebase. I download the images inside of the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` where is the right place to set the rowheights of the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Once you've dowloaded an image reload the corresponding row
2. in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` return a value based on the size of the downloaded image

UPDATE

Maintain an array of model objects for your table. Each model object should contain a reference to an image. In `cellForRow` check the corresponding model object. If it contains an image then assign it to the image view. Otherwise start downloading the image. Once it is downloaded put the image into the model object and reload the row.

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` check the model object as well. If it does not contain an image then return some default height. Otherwise return the height of the image.

As for `rowHeight` property it will set height for each row of the table which is defenitely not what you need

Comment: Thank you. How do I access the image that was downloaded and assigned to the UIImageView of the cell during `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` inside of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: As another side note is better to use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` or just directly change the tableView property .rowHeight inside of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: If you're going this route, I would also recommend looking into `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` if you have some performance issues with scrolling.