# Is this the proper way to use heightForRowAt?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im trying to implement dynamically sized row heights based on the size of downloaded images. The problem I am encountering is that the images are not downloaded when the function `heightForRowAt` is run. What is the proper way to implement this code. images is an array of UIImage, rowHeights is an array of type CGFloat and imageURLS is a string array of imageURLS.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reuse", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    ///////////////////////
 if(cell.cellImageView.image == nil){   
        let downloadURL = URL(string: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row])

      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL!) { (data, _, _) in
        if let data = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.cellImageView.image = image
                cell.cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                self.images.insert(image!, at: 0)
                let aspectRatio = Float((cell.cellImageView?.image?.size.width)!/(cell.cellImageView?.image?.size.height)!)
                print("aspectRatio: \(aspectRatio)")
                tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)/aspectRatio)
              print("tableView.rowHeight: \(tableView.rowHeight)")
                self.rowHeights.insert(CGFloat(Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)/aspectRatio), at: 0)
             tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
 }


    ///////////////////////
    return cell
}

//What is the proper way to implement this function
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    print("Im in height for row")
    return CGFloat(0.0)
}
```

Comment: In terms of row height, the best way is to set `estimatedRowHeight` and set `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and then define constraints that automatically size the row for you, without implementing `heightForRowAt` at all. See comments in `heightForRowAt` documentation regarding disadvantage of implementing that method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your help, Im trying to resize the row height so the image remains proportional to its aspect ratio while its width is the size of the device. When I used the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` the row heights and images still remain too small.

Comment: You recently asked this question already (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251345/how-to-create-dynamically-sized-row-heights-based-on-downloaded-image-sizes) and you accepted an answer. If you accepted an answer to the previous question, why are you posting it again as if you didn't accept a solution to this same issue?

Comment: @user372382 - Fair enough. There are always around that with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (updating constraints in `cellForRowAt`), but that's a little complicated so let's set that aside. My first comment, though, still applies. Just reload the row in the completion handler, making sure that (a) this next call of `cellForRowAt` will use the previously retrieved image; and (b) make sure `heightForRowAt` will now returns the right height.

Comment: @Rob I've updated the code as you suggested to check if the image has already been downloaded and then reloaded the row inside of the completion handler. But I'm unable to access the  image size inside of the `heightForRowAt` function. It seems that the `heightForRowAt` function ran before the  `cellForrowAt` function.

Answer (score 1):

If your asynchronous request may change the height of the cell, you should not update the cell directly, but rather you should completely reload the cell.

So, `heightForRowAt` and `cellForRowAt` will be called once for each visible cell before the image is retrieved. Since the image hasn't been retrieved yet, `heightForRowAt` will have to return some fixed value appropriate for a cell with no image. And `cellForRowAt` should detect that the image has not been retrieved and initiate that process. But when the image retrieval is done, rather than updating the cell directly, `cellForRowAt` should call [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows). That will start the process again for this row, including triggering `heightForRowAt` to be called again, too. But this time, the image should be there, so `heightForRowAt` can now return an appropriate height and `cellForRowAt` can now just update the image view with no further network request.

For example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var objects: [CustomObject]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        objects = [
            CustomObject(imageURL: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Second_Life_Landscape_01.jpg")!),
            CustomObject(imageURL: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Brorfelde_landscape_2.jpg")!)
        ]
    }

    let imageCache = ImageCache()

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let imageURL = objects[indexPath.row].imageURL
        if let image = imageCache[imageURL] {
            // if we got here, we found image in our cache, so we can just 
            // update image view and we're done

            cell.customImageView.image = image
        } else {
            // if we got here, we have not yet downloaded the image, so let's
            // request the image and then reload the cell

            cell.customImageView.image = nil  // make sure to reset the image view

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { data, _, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                    return
                }
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.imageCache[imageURL] = image
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // NB: This assumes that rows cannot be inserted while this asynchronous
                        // request is underway. If that is not a valid assumption, you will need to
                        // go back to your model and determine what `IndexPath` now represents
                        // this row in the table.

                        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .middle)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let imageURL = objects[indexPath.row].imageURL
        if let image = imageCache[imageURL] {
            let size = image.size
            return view.bounds.size.width * size.height / size.width
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Where a simple image cache (which is not relevant to your question, but I include for the sake of completeness) is as follows:

```
class ImageCache {
    private let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()

    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol!

    init () {
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.cache.removeAllObjects()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    subscript(key: URL) -> UIImage? {
        get {
            return cache.object(forKey: key as NSURL)
        }
        set (newValue) {
            if let image = newValue {
                cache.setObject(image, forKey: key as NSURL)
            } else {
                cache.removeObject(forKey: key as NSURL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, in the event of the else statement where the pictures have not yet been downloaded, where in the code is imageView value being set.

Comment: After it retrieves the image, it does not set the image view, but rather it calls `reloadRows(at:with:)`, which triggers that `cellForRowAt` to be called _again_ for that row. And it is that second call to `cellForRowAt` that updates the image view. But we defer it like that so that we can enjoy the new row height and the specified animation.